# Editing KML with ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

I am attempting to create a model that will do the following.

1. Import multiple KMLs into ArcGIS Pro.
2. Separate the line and point features within the newly created feature classes.
3. Save the lines into a newly established geodatabase
4. Merge all of the imported lines into a new feature
5. Change the symbology of the newly merged line feature (I haven't attempted this yet)

What I have so far.

1. Using Batch Import Data I am able to import the KMLs into ArcGIS Pro
2. Using Iterate Feature Classes I am able to identify only the line features into a newly established geodatabase

Problems so far

1. Within the model I am unable to use all  of the newly saved line features within the merge tool.

**How would I identify all of the newly saved line features within the model?**

My current model is attached.
[image]

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Collect Values tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/collect-values.htm), that will build the **LIST** of featureclasses that would feed into a Merge tool.

You need to do this as sub-model. Read the help file on what a sub-model is, there are plenty examples of this on the forum to research.